# Converting varchar to bigint in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, bigint

I am doing calculation part in SQL for my web app,

I have some scalar variables:

```
declare @calc as bigint
declare @paymentid as nvarchar(50)
```

and I am using the variables like this

```
set @calc =(SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(30), '2017-09-02', 103), '-', ''))
```

This line removes `'-'` and sets the value in `@calc` to (20170902)

```
set @calc = (SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(char(30), '2017-09-02',112), 3, 8))
```

This line is fetching `170902` and sets the value in `@calc` to (170902)

```
set @paymentid =  CAST(@calc as nvarchar(max))+'0001'
```

and this line will set the value of `paymentid` to (1709020001)

But I am getting an error on this line

```
set @calc = (SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(char(30), '2017-09-02',112), 3, 8))
```

and the error is:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 4
>   Error converting data type varchar to bigint

My whole code looks like this

```
declare @calc as bigint
declare @paymentid as nvarchar(50)

set @calc =(SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(30), '2017-09-02', 103), '-', ''))     
set @calc = (SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(char(30), '2017-09-02',112), 3, 8))    
set @paymentid =  CAST(@calc as nvarchar(max))+'0001'
```

Comment: Btw just a side note, you don't actually have to construct a full subquery when assigning a variable to a scalar value. `set @calc =(SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(30), '2017-09-02', 103), '-', '')) ` can be foreshortened to  `set @calc = REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(30), '2017-09-02', 103), '-', '')`

Comment: You are taking way too many steps here... this can be greatly simplified

Comment: I know, but I was only trying to illustrate the point about subqueries. The actual answers do justice to what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
set @calc = (SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(char(30), '2017-09-02',112), 3, 8))
```

to

```
set @calc = (SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(char(30), @calc,112), 3, 8))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make this a lot shorter...

```
declare @paymentid as nvarchar(50)
declare @someDate date = '2017-09-02'

set @paymentid = convert(varchar(12),@someDate,12) + '0001'
select @paymentid
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've got SQL Server 2012 or later, you can do this:

```
declare 
    @now date = getdate(), -- using getdate, but you can put in a hard coded or provided date as necessary
    @paymentid nvarchar(50)

select @paymentid = format(@now, 'yyMMdd0001')

select @PaymentId --1709010001
```

or more succinctly....

```
select @paymentid = format(getdate(), 'yyMMdd0001')
```